# Am gettinf this error when generating ssl certificate in a nginx server

Tags: dns, nginx-config, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-20.04

Requesting a certificate for kuwamjanja.org

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: kuwamjanja.org
Type:   connection
Detail: Fetching http://kuwamjanja.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/IrYC0tYYSUpsjHgazBcoXaIDmtH4zPNOjm_HFU-ZVt0: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary nginx configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure the listed domains point to this nginx server and that it is accessible from the internet.

This was the command

sudo certbot --nginx -d kuwamjanja.org